# Invalid key when accessing admin and cart stops working

Tags: admin, cart, addtocart

Looking for help with the following invalid key error:
[image: Screen Shot]

I keep getting this every couple of days. When it happens the cart seems to stop working too. Nothing gets added when clicking add to cart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happens if the cookie domain in `System > Configuration > Web > Cookies` is different from the actual site domain.

To remove the setting without access to the admin panel:

use the following SQL query on the MySQL console or in a client like phpMyAdmin:

> DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';

clear the cache. If you are using the default file based cache Backend, delete all directories below `var/cache`.

Then as soon as you can log in again, set the correct cookie domain for each website or store

Example: .example.com for example.com

Comment: if the solution is work please accept the answer :)

Comment: It worked straight away! Ive been clearing all sorts and testing. I get it working again but nothing has been the actual fix. Is the cookies the issue of nothing adding to the cart as well? Also what do you recommend as the best cookie settings? Thanks Again :)